# Multiple Rails apps on different Ruby versions on the same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx, passenger, unicorn

In RubyMine I am able to select the target Ruby version for project and run it.

Now about a production.

We have two variants to build a host for Rails apps:

- Apache + Phusion Passenger
- Nginx + Unicorn

How to run on each of these configurations two Rails applications built for different Ruby versions?

Requirements: both apps should run on the same server, on different virtual hosts.

RVM is installed.

Comment: Are you using capistrano for deployment?

Comment: @ivopatty: No, but can use it, if necessary.

Comment: in my personal opinion, that would greatly increase the usability, when using Capistrano, you can easily specify which ruby version to use.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to select a different Ruby version when deploying apps is by using Capistrano for deployment. After capifying your application it is time to add some lines to your `Capfile`

Your `Capfile` should look something like this

```
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
```

This way you load special RVM options into Capistrano so you can specify the ruby version to use.

To specify a specific Ruby version to use, you can add a line to your `deploy.rb` for a system wide deployment option or to your `production.rb` or `staging.rb` if you want different ruby version per server.

By adding the following line you can specify your desired Ruby version:

```
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.0.0-p247'
```

After you have deployed your application you still have to specify which ruby version Passenger will use. You can specify this by editing the apache config file specific to your site or subdomain. When editing your Apache config file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    PassengerRuby /home/someuser/.rvm/wrappers/<ruby-version-here>/ruby
    ******
</VirtualHost>
```

You can see which ruby version you need by first executing `rvm use <ruby version>` and then executing `which ruby` which should give you the path to enter in your VirtualHost file.

Hope that works for you

Comment: Thank you, but Capistrano obviously writes something in some files while deploying for specific Ruby version. What are these files?

Comment: You're right, I forgot indeed that it is still necessary to add a line to Passenger to specify which Ruby version to use.